# Mysql 8.0 "ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 100" when adding index to very large table

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-error-1030

I'm attempting to add an index to a very large table (2B rows) and the command fails after a few hours with:

> ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 100 - 'InnoDB error' from storage engine

I'm finding the InnoDB `100` error code to be ungoogleable. It seems to be running out of some kind of resource, but the server has 128 GB of RAM and tons of disk space. Mysql isn't crashing.

I think maybe I need some config tweaks to give it more juice, but I don't know where to start.

Server version: Server version: 8.0.28
Db engine: InnoDB

Comment: Such a helpful error. Great stuff. Anything interesting in your mysql error log that might help troubleshoot?

Comment: 2022-05-05T09:48:14.920142Z 8 [Warning] [MY-012638] [InnoDB] Retry attempts for writing partial data failed.

Comment: I swear sometimes mysql is a black box. Any lines above that line that suggest what happened? Like [this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99293) that might point to a resource issue, like you suspect. Given what you said about this system I'm not convinced it is a resource issue, but it does *feel* like one.

Comment: No it's the first error log since the server comes online. Not much to go on!

Comment: I'm past my low level of expertice and I'm surprised other's haven't weighed in here. Two things for next steps 1) Check out [this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log-filtering.html) for increasing verbosity of error logging in mysql. Seems like a long shot, but who knows. 2) Take this question over to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ and have those folks take a crack at it.

Comment: That's probably where I suggested checking `tmpdir`.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, mystery solved. It turns out mysql by default writes temporary table data to /tmp (not your mysql data dir). Ordinarily you'd probably never notice this, but it can be a LOT of data if you're doing something absurd like creating indexes on 2 billion rows.

In my case the root partition filled to 100%, causing the index command to fail. After which it quietly freed up its temp storage just to make it harder for me to diagnose.

The solution: move the temp directory to a location with more space:

```
sudo nano /[config path]/my.cnf
```

Add:

```
tmpdir=/[new tempdir path]/mytempdir
```

Set perms:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /[new tempdir path]/mytempdir
```

Restart mysql:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Comment: Great find. Thank you for sharing. If you have monitoring on your server enabled using tools like DataDog, PRTG, NewRelic, SolarWinds or such, you might be able to catch partition growth and other resource spikes. Those monitoring tools can point to the problem quickly also.